# The server is behaving as if it is blocked but i have set it to non blocking

Tags: python, networking

The server only listens for a message from the first socket to connect, even though it is set to nonblocking, it doesn't skip over it when it doesn't receive data.  I'm new to networking and this is my first project, if anyone know of any others good for beginners please let me know.  Thanks!  Here is the code.

```
import socket

CONNECTED_SENDERS = []
CONNECTED_LISTENERS = []

def Main():
    HOST = socket.gethostname()
    PORT = 4444

    SERVER_SOCKET = socket.socket()
    SERVER_SOCKET.bind((HOST, PORT))

    SERVER_SOCKET.listen(1)

    for i in range(2):
        CONNECTION, ADDRESS = SERVER_SOCKET.accept()
        CONNECTED_LISTENERS.append(CONNECTION)

    for i in range(2):
        CONNECTION, ADDRESS = SERVER_SOCKET.accept()
        CONNECTED_SENDERS.append(CONNECTION)

    for DEVICE in CONNECTED_LISTENERS:
        DEVICE.send(b'SERVER: You have succesfully connected.')
        DEVICE.send(b'SERVER: Please wait for permission to talk.')

    x = 0
    for DEVICE in CONNECTED_LISTENERS:
        DEVICE.send(b'SERVER: What is your name?')
        Name = CONNECTED_SENDERS[x].recv(1024)
        CONNECTED_LISTENERS[x] = (CONNECTED_LISTENERS[x], Name)
        x += 1
    del x, Name
    for DEVICE, _ in CONNECTED_LISTENERS:
        DEVICE.send(b'SERVER: You may now talk.')

    SERVER_SOCKET.setblocking(0)
    LEAVE = False
    while LEAVE == False:
        try:
            MESSAGE = CONNECTED_SENDERS[0].recv(1024)
            NAME = CONNECTED_LISTENERS[0][1]
            for DEVICE, _ in CONNECTED_LISTENERS:
                DEVICE.send(NAME + b': ' + MESSAGE)
            if MESSAGE == 'QUIT':
                LEAVE = True
        except:
            try:
                MESSAGE = CONNECTED_SENDERS[1].recv(1024)
                NAME = CONNECTED_LISTENERS[1][1]
                for DEVICE, _ in CONNECTED_LISTENERS:
                    DEVICE.send(NAME + b': ' + MESSAGE)
                if MESSAGE == 'QUIT':
                    LEAVE = True
            except:
                pass


    for CONNECTION in CONNECTED_LISTENERS:
        CONNECTION.close()
    for CONNECTION in CONNECTED_SENDERS:
        CONNECTION.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues with your code, some small and some big. But the main problem is that you're marking the *server* socket nonblocking, not any of the sockets *on which communication takes place*.

In standard TCP socket programming, you set up a server which listens for incoming connections. When that server accepts a new client, this returns a *new* socket, and it's on this new socket that all communication with the remote client happens. In other words, the server socket is just for accepting new connections, and nothing else. You never write data through the server socket.

So it doesn't matter that `SERVER_SOCKET` is marked nonblocking, you must do something like this:

```
conn, addr = server.accept()
conn.setblocking(False)
```

`conn` is the new socket through which you talk to the client, and can be used in a nonblocking fashion.

---

#### Smaller issues:

I should also point out that you call `SERVER_SOCKET.listen(1)`. That argument of `1` means that the server will only have a backlog of waiting connections from *one* client. So if a second client connects before the first connection is made, the second client will receive an error, `ECONNREFUSED`. Given what it looks like you're trying to do, I'd guess `SERVER_SOCKET.listen(4)` is appropriate.

Next, nonblocking communication is much harder than blocking protocols. I'd suggest you improve your networking skills before tackling them, but when you're ready, look at the `select` or `selectors` modules for help. They provide tools to wait for communication from any of a number of clients, rather than looping over them all and checking if data is available, as you've done here. This looping is very inefficient.

Finally, in Python, it's good practice to name variables with lower case, underscore-separated names. `UPPER_CASE_NAMES` are usually reserved for constants. So change `SERVER_SOCKET` to `server_socket`, `CONNECTED_LISTENERS` to `connected_listeners`, etc.

Comment: The platform can adjust the `listen()` argument up or down silently. The minimum backlog on any platform ever encountered is 5.

Comment: @EJP I know the argument is a suggestion, but I've never seen anything about explicit minimal or maximal values. POSIX doesn't seem to make any guarantees about it. Where did you get the number 5?